# Saving document to second RavenDb from MVC webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ravendb

I've got a project I've inherited and I've recently just started working with RavenDb.  I'm needing to save a document to one database that already has a connection with, but I need to save that document to a second RavenDb.  Just wondering how I would go about that?  Below is the method I would need to alter.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveContact(ContactInput input)
    {
        var id = getId();
        var profile = RavenSession.Load<TechProfile>(id) ?? new TechProfile();
        input.MapPropertiesToInstance(profile);

        // check for existing user
        if (RavenSession.Query<TechProfile>().Any(x => x.Email == profile.Email && x.Id != profile.Id))
        {
            return Json(new {error = "Profile already exists with that email address.", msg = "Error"});
        }
        RavenSession.Store(profile);
        return Json(new {error = "", msg = "Success", id = profile.Id.Substring(profile.Id.LastIndexOf("/") + 1)});
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a *second* session and point it toward the second database.
Entities aren't tied to a particular session in RavenDB, so you can do that.

Comment: Thank you very much this was exactly what I needed to know.